# Retrieve password from Import-Clixml to login sqlplus using Powershell Get-credential

Tags: powershell, sqlplus

I have a powershell script that will automatically run the SQL query in the SQLPlus hourly through the task scheduler.

The below code run successfully.

```
$username = "abcuser";
$password = "123pw";

$dir = "D:\SQL\Test"
cd $dir

echo exit | sqlplus $username/$password '@Justscript.sql
```

But I want to store the credentials through **Get-Credential** for security, thus did it this way. Note that I have already ran the Get-credential and exported the credentials

```
$db_filename = 'C:\Users\Maria Maria\db_credentials.txt'
$db_cred = Import-Clixml -Path $db_filename
$dir = "D:\SQL\Test"

cd $dir

#this doesn't work
echo exit | sqlplus $db_cred '@Justscript.sql
```

this doesn't work either

```
$username = $db_cred.UserName;
$password = $db_cred.Password;
echo exit | sqlplus $username/$password '@Justscript.sql
```

This was able to read the username, but the password don't. Do you have other way?

Comment: For security reasons, I do not recommend to send credentials as command parameters, as they will be visible in the process list, nor should you store them in an unencrypted text file.

Comment: I stored them in an encrypted text file using export-clixml, I agree but sqlplus was not able to read the hashed password, will think of another way thought, will push this first for testing. Thank you. Or do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get the plaintext data from `Get-Credential`:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential
$username = $credentials.UserName
$password = $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password
```